# Is it possible to automatically restore in app purchases on iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm going to be adding the ability to remove ads from a free app that I currently have on the App Store. I know I'll need a way to "restore" the IAP to devices that have reinstalled the app, etc.

Is there a way to automatically determine whether or not the user has purchased and installed the "upgrade", perhaps in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, etc? I can include a restore button, but I think it would be neat to automatically restore without the user having to think about doing it. Is this something that can/is being done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's awesome that you're thinking about little details like that. Keep it up!

Unfortunately, **there is a reason that this isn't done** in apps: the dreaded password dialog. When attempting to restore IAP's, the system asks the user for their iTunes Store password.

It's not really the best user experience to have a big ugly password dialog come up as soon as an app is opened. The user (if security conscious) will probably dismiss the dialog.

On the other hand, users are used to pressing a 'restore purchases' button. It makes sense that to restore a purchase a password is required, and thus they will give it.

Just implement the standard, plain, boring restore button. Keep thinking of these little things, though!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I hadn't even thought about the password dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I also missed the password dialog.